# What headers have to be present in HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 POST requests?

Tags: http, header, http-post

What headers are mandatory and have to be present in HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 POST requests?

Answer (score -1):

Content-Length is a mandatory header in POST because the browser should be able to estimate how much loading is remained to show a progress bar to user (for example).